# CSS SASS trim converted decimal

Tags: sass

How can edit my em() conversion function, to limit the following converted EM value to 3 digits (example: 1.36em)?

input.scss

```
@function em($target, $context: $font___base-size) {
    @return ($target / $context) * 1em;
}
body {font-size:em(15px);}
```

output.css

```
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.36364em; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `round()` `ceil()` or `floor()` like so:

```
round( ($target / $context)*100 ) / 100;
```

100 can be any number 10^n where n is then number of decimal places you want.

[Sass-lang documentation on round()](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html#round-instance_method)

Comment: Thanks Lucas, I modified my function to work exactly as 'pxtoem':

Answer (score 0):

I would go for something like this :

```
// Configuration
$font___base-size : 11px;
$number-of-digits : 2;

// Function
@function em($target, $digits : $number-of-digits, $context: $font___base-size) {
    $n : 1;
    @if $digits > 0 {
        @for $i from 1 through $digits {
            $n : $n * 10;
        }
    }
    @return round(($target / $context) * $n) / $n * 1em;
}

// Example use
body {
    font-size:em(15px);
}
```

Output :

```
body {
  font-size: 1.36em;
}
```